# Find minimum quantity inside nested array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My collection contains a document `legends` with a nested array `value` containing nested documents. I need to find the minimum quantity (single value) for each document inside the `BASIC` array inside `value`.

Here is a [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/T2pGAd2E7AR) that contains both the collection and my attempt. As you can see from the result the `$min` operator doesn't return a single value but all the `quantity` from the documents of the `BASIC` array but, for instance, I need the minimum single value that for the `meteoEventType` equals to `RAIN` should be 0.01.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `$$thresholds.BASIC.quantity` returns a nested array, you need to flatten the array via `$reduce` operator and combine arrays into one with `$concatArrays`.

```
{
  $addFields: {
    rainMinThreshold: {
      $let: {
        vars: {
          thresholds: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$value",
              as: "v",
              cond: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$v.meteoEventType",
                  "RAIN"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        in: {
          $min: {
            $reduce: {
              input: "$$thresholds",
              initialValue: [],
              in: {
                $concatArrays: [
                  "$$value",
                  "$$this.BASIC.quantity"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fjat1aaH7Y3)

Comment: Why does `$$thresholds.BASIC.quantity` return a nested array?

Comment: Hi, if you read the data, the `thresholds` variable which is the `VALUE` array, And in each element of `VALUE` array, the `BASIC` field is an array too. So when you access the `$$thresholds.BASIC.quantity`, it returns you a nested array like: `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`. You can try to use your Mongo Playground link and remove the `$min` operator, you will see the result like this: [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yF4wFppDEX3)